# Http Get Request returns html?

Tags: android, json, http, android-activity

i am using http get Request for loading a data in android . Don't know it returns html instead of JSON result. The same URL get the json when loading in the browser but in response coming html.

my Http Get call format Like this...

```
url = new URL(urlString);

        //httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");

        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json"); // or application/jsonrequest
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        /*
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");*/
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("UseCookieContainer", "True");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cokieValue);
        httpURLConnection.connect();
```

Comment: How does the server decide which format to send back? You need to find this out and then write the Android app accordingly.

Comment: looks like you are getting 404 html page or some other error

Comment: no sir i am getting response code as 200 , The Response code only getting html

Comment: Check this web service in poster plugin (web browser ), and then test in code.

Comment: please check the url, which returns the result . please return the result as JSON Result instead of ActionResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you check the server side code as well..
after the is coming means change the code like this...

```
url = new URL(urlString);

        httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        //httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    //  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new NullHostNameVerifier());
        httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/json");
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("UseCookieContainer", "True");
        httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
        httpURLConnection.connect();

        if (httpURLConnection != null) {
            respCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
            messageStatus.setResponseCode(respCode);
        }
        if (respCode == 200) {
            InputStream responseStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            messageStatus.setResponseStream(responseStream);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you in control of the target web service?

Have you tried "text/x-json" as the content type. Recently found out myself that some systems don't support application/json even though it's the standard.

Answer (score 1):

The server must return JSON, not just printing. 
If you use PHP for example, use:

```
print(json_encode($response));
```

not simple print method.